# How can I edit and add nested data in json file?

Tags: java, json, database, nosql, gson

This was just to test though but basically what it does is when it receives a message(message would be like abc/xyz/pq=yo) then makes a out of it like:- `{"root":[{"abc":[{"xyz":[{"pq":"yo"}]}]}]}` but whet I want is for example there exists a json already and if someone wants to add value like abc/xyz/lm=ayo then if it doesn't exist then it will add that to the existing json. and if someone wants to update something like abc/xyz/pq=ayo then it will update it. That is if there exists a child then it updates a value else it creates it.

in case you are wondering why the json have an array even for a single child i.e. because in case if we want to add data to particular child we can easily add.

Please keep in mind this was just test code I in readFileResult() but I want to change entire structure.

Update:- as I know the exact path when user wants to add data I can easily add data to that path but the problem is how to check how to check if there exists data? As I've nested child in Arrays('{"root":[{"abc":[{"xyz":[{"pq":"yo"}]}]}]}') I can not loop through each child and parse it coz it would be consuming a lot of resources and time.

Another Update:- I've changed the structure to rfc8259 to get rid of these arrays. This should be simpler but still struggling in "updating" the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another better way to fix this, I changed the structure a little bit. and Instead of using JSONWriter and JSONArray, I just used JSONObjects to query and edit objects easily. You can check [this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69482867/13327203)

Answer (score 0):

For inserting objects to JSON if it does not exit or updating if it exists, I think there are multiple ways. Now I don't know your limitations of use case but simplest one would be like below pseudo code :

```java
- get root level json object

- get input from user e.g. abc/xyz/lm=ayo

- split input first by '=' for value at index 1 and then by '/' for keys.

- Now iterate over keys
    + Find in object is key exists.
    + If key exists, get json object for that key and check for next keys inside this object.
    + If key does not exist, add keys in hierarchy and at last key, store above value.
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I've already implemented 1st 3 steps. I tried several different ways in last 3 days but wasn't able to accomplish that. I also tried a while loop to play with keys but it didn't work as I said each child is in array so like root:[...] so it only returns 1 key i.e. root

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                Iterator<String> x = jsonObject.keys();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                while (x.hasNext()){
                    String key  = x.next();
                    array.put(jsonObject.get(key));
                    System.out.println(key);
                }
                System.out.println(array);`

this just gives 1 key

i.e. root

for nested objects if I try and verify each key.. that would be very bad for performance